# Can't find file: Errno 2 No such file or directory : Even after going to the correct directory and setting up the correct environment variable

Tags: python, argv

I have set up the environment variable correctly and I am in the correct directory and I am still getting the following error:

```
 C:\Users\Sherw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Sherw\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PycharmProjects\\Lab07\\venv\\Scripts\\cowsay.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the cowsay.py file is in the directory C:\Users\Sherw\OneDrive\Desktop\PycharmProjects\Lab07\venv\Scripts  so as you can see I am running the file from the correct directory.

'C:\Users\Sherw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310' I have added this path to the user environment variable.

I dont know why I am still getting the error.

Please let me know the solution to this problem.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to go directly into the `venv\Scripts` folder and just do `python cowsay.py` ? By the way,  `venv\Scripts` is quite an unusual folder for your scripts. You should place them in a dedicated folder or at least at the same level than venv folder.

Comment: tried to move the script in local, not in onedrive ?

Answer (score 0):

Try relocating the cowsay.py into another folder alongside its dependencies, e.g. the downloads folder.

Open a cmd window and cd into `C:\\Users\\YOURNAME\\Downloads`(change YOURNAME to your usename)

Now use the command `where python` to get the path of the python executable you are actually running. Make sure that is where you think python.exe should be. Also at this point make sure you have installed python from python.org and NOT the microsoft store. If you installed from microsoft store uninstall from control panel and download python [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.5/python-3.10.5-amd64.exe) instead. Delete any PATH changes you made beforehand and reboot if you needed to reinstall python.

After go back, open a cmd window and cd back into `C:\\Users\\YOURNAME\\Downloads`(change YOURNAME to your usename), and type `python cowsay.py` which should run. Try again in your venv location, although it is a really unconventional place to put your file in. If it works in the Downloads folder only it is an environment error and you may want to recreate the venv.